Seeking Advice on Restricting Kafka ACLs for Specific Operations
I’m facing a challenge with Kafka ACLs regarding the “Alter Cluster” privilege. When granted, this privilege allows users to manage their ACLs (due to inheriting CREATE_ACLS and DELETE_ACLS), but it also enables them to add ClusterAction and AlterConfigs permissions on the “Cluster” resource. This is a concern because it could allow users to modify broker configurations, which we want to prevent.
I’m considering two potential solutions and would appreciate your thoughts or suggestions:
1. Using PolicyViolationException
Is there a way to leverage PolicyViolationException to block users from adding ClusterAction or AlterConfigs permissions specifically for the “Cluster” resource?
2. Custom Authorizer
Could we modify the Kafka source code to implement a custom authorizer? For example, tweaking the StandardAuthorizer to explicitly deny these operations. Here’s a conceptual implementation:
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclOperation;

@Override
public List<AuthorizationResult> authorize(
        AuthorizableRequestContext requestContext,
        List<Action> actions) {
    List<AuthorizationResult> results = new ArrayList<>(actions.size());
    StandardAuthorizerData curData = data;

    for (Action action : actions) {
        // Explicitly deny AlterConfigs and ClusterAction
        if (action.operation() == AclOperation.ALTER_CONFIGS || 
            action.operation() == AclOperation.CLUSTER_ACTION) {
            results.add(AuthorizationResult.DENIED);
        } else {
            // Default authorization logic
            AuthorizationResult result = curData.authorize(requestContext, action);
            results.add(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

Both approaches are theoretical at this stage, and I haven’t implemented them yet.
Does anyone have experience with these methods or insights into their feasibility? Is there a better alternative?

I have identified potential solutions outlined in my question, but I’m looking for expert guidance to develop a detailed implementation plan.

Please consider asking a much more focused question.

Please consider not using Chatgpt to make your questions for you. If you don't have the knowledge to compose your own question how do you expect to accomplish this task?
